# Is GPS tracking down the exact lane with Google Maps possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The newest Google maps release has a database of all the lanes available when you are near an highway exit and it highlights which lane you should be in if you want to take the exit. I am wondering if google maps API now has a feature to track cars down to the exact lane they are in. Is this possible? And if so, with which specific API?